# Can't Install ADT. org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui is missing

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am having trouble getting the Android Development Tools to install.  I overcame one error involving the GEF.  I now have a new error.

Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I am running Kubuntu 9.10 and Eclipse 3.5.  I have managed to get the Android DDMS to install.  But I keep running into blocks with the Development Tools.  I have the Android SDK installed.

What do I need to do in order get the missing component?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ran into the same problem, and after a bit of searching, I found this:

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#wstinstallerror

It looks like fedora ships with the official eclipse repository disabled by default.  (was true for me on fedora 12 64bit)  You need to go to Help->Install New Software, click on the "Available Software Sites" link, find the official repository in the list, and enable it.

Comment: Also, make sure "Contact all Update Sites" is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I never use Eclipse classic as ADt requires wst..install eclipse j2ee or modeling to fix missing components

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I did not precisely follow the order of the installation instructions.  Delete your eclipse install and reinstall, run update until it doesn't find anything new, then install the android plugin checking the box that says to search all sites for required packages.  It should clean it right up.  You'll still need to do all the configuration in the developer.android.com instructions for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

I had to add the plugin for (in my case) galilio, by adding
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo in the install new software tab,
then selected each of the WST packages (the xml one alone didnt resolve it).
They were listed twice (same version, different checksums), so I choose the first of each.

HTH,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

I was having this trouble for a couple weeks then i noticed my Anti-Virus icon (AVG) kept popping up beside my clock when i normally have it hidden.
I disabled my anti-virus and the web link scanner and tried again.

Worked fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @KailashDabhi - Do not insert random formatting into an existing answer where it isn't needed. This makes things harder to read, so I've rolled back your edit.