# How to install the Android ADT Plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt, eclipse-3.5

I followed the instructions on [ADT Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) but I got this message when installing in Eclipse:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 
      (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953
      (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953)
      requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I have tried with both 64bit and 32bit Eclipse Galileo fresh installs. I am using Windows 7.

**Update:** I followed the steps on [org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0 required for installing Android Development Tools on Eclipse 3.5.1](http://tewson.com/content/orgeclipsegef-000-required-installing-android-development-tools-eclipse-351) and installed GEF SDK 3.5.2 but now I got a new similar error message when installing ADT:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 
      (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953
      (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953)
      requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

How can I install the Android ADT Plugin for Eclipse 3.5.2 on Windows?

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows/Linux/Mac? Have you tried the eclipse classic? (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-361/heliossr1) I think I got a similar error when I was setting up my development environment but using eclipse classic fixed it.

Comment: Yes, it's the Eclipse Classic both 32bit and 64bit on Windows 7 I have tested. They are fresh installs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally followed the instructions on [During installation, there's an error about requiring org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui. How do I fix that?](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/eclipse/docs/faq.html#wstinstallerror) and installed [Google Plugin for Eclipse Galileo](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.5.html), then the installation of Android ADT Plugin worked without any problem, finally.

Comment: On Fedora check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2526167/669527 (points to the same location, but emphasize problem with org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui)

Comment: Answers should not include links that are dead.

Comment: Both links are 404 at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

On ubuntu 11 it installs Eclipse 3.7 (indigo). To make it work i had to add http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo to the list of sources. After that it worked like a charm.

Comment: The same, added the url http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo  to the list of sources and the download started right away.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7, run Eclipse using **As Administrator**.

PS: I made it in conjunction with other advices like adding Indigo release URL to available sources and using HTTP instead of HTTPS, and I didn't tested if all three requirements must be met or the first is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

1. Go to Help->Install New Software
2. Go to "Available software sources"
3. Check all the boxes
4. Try the official instructions again.  http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Answer (score 2):

Installing on 3.7 Indigo, I found the plug-in is now called:

> **WST Server Adapters**
>
> org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message in Galileo then I installed Indigo and it worked although I checked only dev tools and plugins the other two I didn't install and had some error with those. But the ADT works now.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud set your computer's connection to no proxy, and run eclipse as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is upgrading from eclipse 3.6 and they've copied (overwritten or merged) their directories you will get a conflicting dependency error and ADT won't install.
Make sure you go back , delete eclipse, unzip the new eclipse fresh to the new location and run it!
Worked for me!