# Android Create Project Eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, project

Installed Android SDK and Eclipse. Everything was setup according to the instructions however when I tried to create a new project there is no option. I get other options but no New Android Project. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Preference setup in Eclipse
http://s11.postimage.org/g6hpno8nn/image.jpg

New Project
http://s16.postimage.org/6gb9kxzzp/image.jpg

Comment: ``Android Project`` is also known as ``Android Application Project``.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it's because you don't have *Android Development Tool plug-in* (ADT) Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click in navigator - > New Project - > other - >  Android - > Android Application Project/Android Project ( whichever is availaible, they mean the same)

Answer (score 0):

select `Android Application Project`.

It has a few difference option to `Android Project`
but you can use it

Comment: I tried to run the first basic tutorial from the SDK development site and using Android Application Project instead of Android Project I couldn't run it. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

android SDK and eclipse is not enough for you to create project. You have to install ADT plugin for eclipse.

ADT plugin :
[Download link for ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Installation : [Installing ADT in eclipse see this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935956/how-to-install-the-android-adt-plugin-in-eclipse)

Comment: In this image http://s16.postimage.org/6gb9kxzzp/image.jpg, you choose Android->Android Application Project

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Window -> Customize Perspective ... Check the Android Wizards chekbox is checked.
You can unchek it and recheck it to see where the "New Adroid Project wizard" ICON is placed.
There will be 3 Android wizard icons on top.